# Is it allowed in YARN to have multiple containers on same DataNode?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

Is it allowed in YARN to have "multiple containers" of the "same application" running on one DataNode?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Example: multiple mappers of a job running on same DN

Answer (score 1):

Yes, any data node can have multiple containers running in parallel.

The number of parallel containers is calculated by the YARN resource manager by considering the amount of ram memory , cpu cores available on the data node.

There are chances to see multiple containers running on the same data node when resource manager decides to run multiple mappers/reducers on the containers of a data node.